# RecyclerView animation when for replacing entire DataSet

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

So I was working with RecyclerView animations, and implemented an animation for when the items load into the List. I was wondering, if I can make an animation for when I replace the entire data set (an animation including the items joining and leaving the RecyclerView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to remove an item from a recycler view is to remove the item from the data set and them inform the adapter that the item is removed. If you do this then the animation would happen similar to the animation that happens when you add an item.

```
myDataset.remove(position); // myDataset is List<MyObject>
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);//this line is important
```

If you are not using the second line then...

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

will be called and the animation will stop.

Comment: Still appers like every item is removed at once.